# Need to call parents function from jquery iframe dialog

Tags: jquery

1) Frame.jsp

```
<div id="existingEndorsement" style="font-size:12px; height:200px !important; display: none;" >
    <iframe id="existingEndorsementFrame" width="410" height="200"></iframe>
</div>
```

2) ExistingEndorsement.jsp

```
function openExistingEndorsementPopup() {
      parent.$("#existingEndorsementFrame").attr('src', ExistingEndorsementAlert.jsp);
        parent.$("#existingEndorsement").dialog({ title: "Existing Incomplete Endorsement " });
        parent.$("#existingEndorsement").dialog( "open" );
    }
```

3. ExistingEndorsementAlert.jsp -- I have button. On click of which i want to call function which is present in EndorsementBasicInfo.jsp

Answer (score 0):

You can use **top** for parent elements in iframe;

```
function openExistingEndorsementPopup() {
        top.$("#existingEndorsementFrame").attr('src', ExistingEndorsementAlert.jsp);
        top.$("#existingEndorsement").dialog({ title: "Existing Incomplete Endorsement " });
        top.$("#existingEndorsement").dialog( "open" );
}
```

Comment: I am able to open the popup but on click of button on popup I want to call parents function.. Preveously I was usinh window.showmodaldialg.. But now I reaplaced it with jquery dialog. Since jquery dialog does not return anythink unlike window.showmodaldialog I want to go back to the parent and call its function.. Pl help